# why this if else statement not working - kettle javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am using this java script in my kettle spoon ETL workflow. But always only the if statement is working, else if is not working, whats wrong with this?

```
var type1 = '';
var type2 = '';
var category1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 50, 53];
var category2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 56];

if (sub_type_id in category1) {
type1 = 'type-res';}
else if (sub_type_id in category2) {
type1 = 'type-ren';}
else type1 = '';
```

sub_type_id looks like this..

[image]

Comment: What is `sub_type_id` ?

Comment: That will have values like 1,2,3,4..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in javascript, the `in` operator used for array doesn't check values in array, it checks the indexes.

See:

```
var category1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 50, 53];
var sub_type_id = 50;
console.log(sub_type_id in category); // you get false
```

To see this more clearly, if you do:

```
for (i in category1) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

What's printed is 0 ~ 9, which are the indexes, rather than the actual values.

You need to use `indexOf` on array.

Try:

```
if(category1.indexOf(sub_type_id) !== -1) {
  // do something
} else if (category2.indexOf(sub_type_id) !== -1) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: It is not working. :( Now even if statement is not working. empty cells.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of `sub_type_id` that you were using.

Comment: Edited the question with sub_type_id

Comment: Hi, I created this fiddle snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/k5ahwzue/.
It looks printing correctly.
Can you put some prints to check if each branch is hit correctly

Comment: I tried to run, sorry I couldn't run it. I never used this, I am not a javascript person, I am using this script inside ETL tool called pentaho - kettle. :(